# Looping music with .play() .pause() button in HTML5-Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to loop music embedded in HTML5-Canvas with an onClick event listener but cannot find a method to make it loop. Audio is functional but only for a single loop. This is only meant to be single track audio on loop indefinitely until "muted" for a game.

This is the code for "muting" and "unmuting" the audio track:

```js
// true means muted, false means unmuted
mutedToggleStatus = true
function toggleMute() {
    mutedToggleStatus = !mutedToggleStatus;
    if (mutedToggleStatus === true) {
        music.pause();
    } else if (mutedToggleStatus === false) {
        music.play();
    }
}

function drawAudioButton() {
    if (mutedToggleStatus === true) {
        c.save();
        c.drawImage(currentlyMuted, 4, 4);
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)";
        c.fillRect(4, 4, 32, 32) /* this is the hitbox for the audio button */
        c.fill(pathAudio)
        c.restore()
    } else if (mutedToggleStatus === false) {
        c.save();
        c.drawImage(currentlyUnmuted, 4, 4);
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)";
        c.fillRect(4, 4, 32, 32) /* this is the hitbox for the audio button */
        c.fill(pathAudio)
        c.restore()
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawAudioButton);
}
```

... which is defined here:

```js
//music
const music = new Audio();
music.src = "resources/audio.ogg";





// audio button call path
const pathAudio = new Path2D();
pathAudio.rect(4, 4, 32, 32);
pathAudio.closePath();
  
document.addEventListener("click",  function (e) {
  const XY = getXY(canvas, e);
  //use the shape data to determine if there is a collision
  if(c.isPointInPath(pathAudio, XY.x, XY.y)) {
    // Do Something with the click
    if (splashScreenState === false) {
      toggleMute();
    }
  }
}, false);
```

I had success looping when using the audio embedded into the body itself, but I wanted the audio controls linked to custom buttons inside the canvas, which did not work for me by putting the  tag inside the canvas element. I don't need anything but volume (not yet implemented) and looping for the current music.play() method if possible.

Comment: Try [`music.loop = true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the audio loop indefinitely in your HTML5 Canvas game, you can set the `loop` property of the `Audio` element to `true`. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. Update the creation of the `Audio` element to set the `loop` property:

   ```js
   const music = new Audio();
   music.src = "resources/audio.ogg";
   music.loop = true; // Set loop to true for indefinite looping
   ```
2. Remove the condition that pauses and plays the audio when the mute button is clicked since you want the audio to loop indefinitely:

   ```js
   // Comment out or remove this part
   /*
   function toggleMute() {
       mutedToggleStatus = !mutedToggleStatus;
       if (mutedToggleStatus === true) {
           music.pause();
       } else if (mutedToggleStatus === false) {
           music.play();
       }
   }
   */

   // Modify this part to simply toggle the mute status
   function toggleMute() {
       mutedToggleStatus = !mutedToggleStatus;
   }

   // Remove the condition for toggling mute in drawAudioButton function
   function drawAudioButton() {
       if (mutedToggleStatus === true) {
           // Draw the muted audio button
       } else if (mutedToggleStatus === false) {
           // Draw the unmuted audio button
       }
       window.requestAnimationFrame(drawAudioButton);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I must have misread the documentation, I thought music.loop was a method and I was using it as music.loop(), so I thought it was only a method for the <audio> tag. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it works for you!